# Proxy dash on twisted using nginx results in "Error loading layout"

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, twisted, plotly-dash

I implemented a dash dashboard for running in a productive scenario with twisted by (relevant code of **my_dashboard.py**)

```
import dash
import flask
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource
import werkzeug.serving

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)
app.layout = html.Div(html.P('My dashboard content'))

def run_twisted_wsgi():
    reactor_args = {'installSignalHandlers': False}
    resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), server.wsgi_app)
    site = Site(resource)
    reactor.listenTCP(8050, site)
    reactor.run(**reactor_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_twisted_wsgi = werkzeug.serving.run_with_reloader(run_twisted_wsgi)
    run_twisted_wsgi()
```

Which runs as expected at port 8050. Now I want to proxy the application using nginx to http://my.server/dash/my_dashboard. I use the following configuration in **/etc/nginx/sites-available/my.server.net** (which is as well linked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my.server.net)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.server.net;

  location /dash/my_dashboard {
    proxy_pass  http://0.0.0.0:8050;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

While this does not affect accessing the dashboard by `http://my.server.net:8050` accessing it by the desired `http://my.server.net/dash/my_dashboard gives me a "Error loading layout" instead of the dashboard.

Perhaps it is something with the nginx config wrong or the dash configuration needs special treatment. Can anyone give some advice her?

I tried already the suggested proxyfixes applied on `server.wsgi_app`

```
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
```

and another suggestion

```
class CustomProxyFix(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        host = environ.get('HTTP_X_FHOST', '')
        if host:
            environ['HTTP_HOST'] = host
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

which both have not been able to solve the problem. Perhaps also a change to the dash config might do it, so far I have tried to vary these settings

```
app.config.update({
    'routes_pathname_prefix': '/',
    'requests_pathname_prefix': '/',
    })
```

without success.

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: No. I have not pursued this further.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked over on the Plot.ly forums, I had some success with this issue by changing some of the settings slightly from what you tried:

```
app.config.update({
# remove the default of '/'
'routes_pathname_prefix': '',

# remove the default of '/'
'requests_pathname_prefix': ''
})
```

More info available here: https://community.plot.ly/t/hosting-multiple-dash-apps-with-uwsgi-nginx/6758/2

Comment: Hi! Thanks for following this up. Your suggestion does not seem to work. When accessing the page I still only see "Error loading layout" instead of the actual dashboard.

Comment: I’m not at my computer so I can’t double check my nginx config, but I believe you may also need a trailing slash after the proxy_pass address and/or the location.